# Passing values to javascript onClick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website with some links. when a user clicks on each link it should pass different integer values which I can use in a .js file.
 I have to make some operations on the basis of these integer values. 
please help!!!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Then please post your code snippet.

Comment: What problem do you have? onclick events are one of the most common in js/jQuery. How about trying some tutorials first?

Comment: how is the integer values to be passed defined

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Though this question is most likely to get closed. You can call a function and pass the integer as parameter.

try this

```
 <a href="#"  onclick="yourFunction('1')">click1</a>
 <a href="#"  onclick="yourFunction('2')">click2</a>
```

javascript

```
 function yourFunction(intValue){
   alert(intValue);
}
```

Comment: this is pure javascript :) i know jQuery is javascript, but not all javascript is jQuery :)

Comment: thanks bipin for the help. In the jquery function the parameter intvalue, how will it know that which number is passed from the html page. Suppose I click 1 from html how will 'intvalue' receive 1 in it

Comment: in bipin example when you click on link1 you call function with parameter 1, and if you click on 2nd link you call function with parameter 2. It is simple as that.

Comment: i stuck into one more thing the value which i get from the html file, I have to use that value in the following manner  main_settings:{
url_new_tab: 'no',  
  initial_zoom: getValue(intvalue),  
  initial_zoom_solo: 'no',
  auto_load: 'yes',
  hide_labels: 'no'  
 }

Comment: I have added a new question with the codes.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358877/i-have-a-js-file-which-is-accepting-value-from-a-html-page-i-have-to-use-this-v

Comment: hi @bipen did you find my new added question? Need your help man!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Functions</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function add(firstnum,secondnum) {
     document.write(firstnum+secondnum);
}

</script>
<h1>onclick Function called</h1>
<input type="button" value="Sum Me" onclick="add(2,3)" />
</body>
</html>
```

### Output:

5