# I have a JS file which is accepting value from a HTML page. I have to use this variable inside a CSS embedded inside the JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [simplemaps](http://simplemaps.com/) and this is a js file where a function is used to get values from HTML page.

Javascript function

```
function getValue(intvalue){
alert(intvalue);
var mapval = intvalue;
}
var simplemaps_worldmap_mapdata = {


main_settings:{
//General settings
width:1004,
background_color: '#FFFFFF', 
background_transparent: 'no',
border_color: '#FFFFFF',
zoom: 'yes',
pop_ups: 'detect', //on_click, on_hover, or detect

//Country defaults
state_description:   'Country description',
state_color: '#88A4BC',
state_hover_color: '#3B729F',
state_url: 'http://simplemaps.com',
all_states_inactive: 'no',

//Location defaults
location_description:  'Location description',
location_color: '#FF0067',
location_opacity: 1,
location_url: 'http://simplemaps.com',
location_size: 35,
location_type: 'circle', //or circle
all_locations_inactive: 'no',

url_new_tab: 'no',  
initial_zoom: 1,   
initial_zoom_solo: 'no',
auto_load: 'yes',
hide_labels: 'no'  
},
}//end of simplemaps_worldmap_mapdata
```

I have to dynamically pass value to the 'initial zoom', colors field. At different value it is zooming the image at different levels.

Comment: You'll have to provide wider context to get an answer. What is main_settings used for?

Comment: Wider context and valid code. The code presented has both logical errors (which is fair enough, you're asking a question) and syntax errors (which is less okay).

Comment: added the complete code may this could help

Comment: is this some plugins that you are using... if yes then can u proide the link of the plugin

Comment: yes I am using a plugin. you can download the free code from this URL http://simplemaps.com

Comment: this is a world map with each continent has been assigned as some zoom variable. The site which I am building has all the continents with links which onclick will pass the values so that to achieve the zooming level.. your help is much appreciated

Comment: ok ... if in case your initail_zoom is 2... those this zoom when you click the `<a>` link

Comment: bipen can we have Skype conversation where I can show you the codes and the site to give you the better understanding. I am actually an iphone developer and new to javascript, css and html

Comment: ok wait.. i got the sample codes.. hang on.. i will update you

Comment: thanks buddy!!! anticipating on your response...you rock

Comment: ok the plugins.. does not allows to do that... you can't pass a variable to an object and since the worldmap.js is accepting the `simplemaps_worldmap_mapdata` obj.. on load.. you cannot send the data again..

Comment: ok so what is the alternate can i create several js files with different zoom values and call each on a click

Comment: yes  that is , one way to do it... when click to `<a>` redirect to other page.. with initailzoom to that particular continent ... :)..but the pluigin does have click on map.. whn you click the continent on the map it does take the zoom to that bu default....

Comment: I know that but in my site where I am using this plugin has the names of each continent for ex Africa, north america, europe etc.. On its click it has to open up the map of that particular region that means with their respective zoom value.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what exactly you asking but I guess you need to access the main_settings object

You can access property in object by

`simplemaps_worldmap_mapdata.main_settings.initial_zoom`

and

`simplemaps_worldmap_mapdata["main_settings"]["initial_zoom"];`

[read this](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I need is; can I set the value of the object "initial_zoom: 1", dynamically instead of passing static value 1

Comment: You mean setting zoom level on the runtime right? Have you try checking the document?